# One animation after another in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do one animation after another. So until the first animation completes, then the 2nd one works. Right now, only the first animation works.

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.white-area-comments').animate({
scrollTop: $('.white-area-comments').prop('scrollHeight')
}, 800);


$('#your-rank').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for animate is [`.animate( properties \[, duration \] \[, easing \] \[, complete \] )`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#basic-usage) so call it when the animation is complete.

```
$('.white-area-comments').animate({
    scrollTop: $('.white-area-comments').prop('scrollHeight')
}, 800, function () {
    $('#your-rank').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the animation return a `Promise` that will resolve once it's completed:

```
$('.white-area-comments')
    .animate({ ... }, 800)
    .promise()
    .done(function() {
         $('#your-rank').fadeIn('slow');
     });
```

See [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)